# How to upload python files in Flink Web UI?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I can only see the button where to upload jar files.

I am wondering how to upload a Python file in Flink web UI?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported currently.

You can watch the [relevant PR](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/8532).